# Is it safe to use $|f(x)|<g(x)\iff -g(x)<f(x)<g(x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, propositional-calculus

Some peoples often use the following.

$$|f(x)|<g(x)\iff -g(x)<f(x)<g(x)$$

The weird part occurs when $g(x)<0$, for example:

$$10<f(x)<-10\to |f(x)|<-10$$

where $x\in\{\}$  for both sides of implication which is  true.

Is it safe to use $|f(x)|<g(x)\iff -g(x)<f(x)<g(x)$?

Comment: Yes it is safe.

Comment: Yeah, this looks ok to me. But using $\leq$ instead of $<$ would make this a little sounder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct. If you have $|f(x)|<g(x)$, then $g$ must be positive everywhere since $0 \le |f(x)|$. Conversely, if $-g(x)<f(x)<g(x)$, the again $g$ must be positive everywhere because we have $-g(x)<g(x)$ which is impossible if $g(x) \le 0$.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, how about the following, is it still safe?
$$|f(x)|>g(x) \iff f(x)<-g(x) \quad \text{or}\quad f(x)>g(x)$$

Comment: Yes, this is also correct.

Answer (score 2):

For each $f(x)$ and negative $g(x),$ $$|f(x)|<g(x)$$ and $$-g(x)<f(x)<g(x)$$ are both false. Hence, by [deductive explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion), $$\forall f \;\;\forall g<0 \bigg(|f(x)|<g(x)\; \iff \; -g(x)<f(x)<g(x)\bigg).$$

---

Also for each $f(x)$ and negative $g(x),$ $$|f(x)|> g(x)$$ and $$f(x)<-g(x) \;\text{ or }\; f(x)> g(x)$$ are both true. Hence, since [a true consequent automatically means a true implication](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1306280/21813), $$\forall f \;\;\forall g<0 \bigg(|f(x)|> g(x)\;\iff \; f(x)<-g(x) \;\text{ or }\; f(x)> g(x) \bigg).$$