# Why aren't vacuous truths just undefined?

Tags: logic, definition, propositional-calculus

I am struggling to understand this. According to truth tables, if $P$ is false, it doesn't matter whether $Q$ is true or not: Either way, $P \implies Q$ is true.

Usually when I see examples of this people make up some crazy premise for $P$ as a way of showing that $Q$ can be true or false when $P$ is something outrageous and obviously untrue, such as "If the moon is made of bacon-wrapped apple-monkey carburetors, then I am a better wakeborder than Gauss."

$P$ is clearly false, but $P \implies Q$ is true no matter what the state of $Q$ is, and I don't understand why.

Are we saying "If $P$ is false, then all bets are off and $Q$ can be anything, either true or false, and not contradict our earlier claim, and if it isn't false, it must be true"?

Otherwise why can't we say that if $P$ is false, then we can't make any claims one way or the other on whether or not it implies anything at all?

Comment: I doubt that a really good answer suitable for a broad audience of intelligent layersons and philosophers has ever been written for this excellent question. $\qquad$

Comment: Part of the answer is that one wants to be able to fill in the truth table with a value for $P\Rightarrow Q$ based ONLY on the truth values of $P$ and $Q$ and not on anything else about the content of $P$ and $Q$. $\qquad$

Comment: Well most of the answers I see say something like "Well it hasn't been proven false, so we say it's true." What I want to know is whether or not this result has been arbitrarily decided by humans as a convention or if it is a consequence of some other mathematical truth / structure / something / anything. And then this answer here http://math.stackexchange.com/a/440242/70349 suggests that it is NOT mere convenience.

Comment: $\ldots\,$ and that is a lousy answer. $\qquad$

Comment: It's just a convention, but one that has proven to be very convenient.

Comment: This follows from the principle of explosion and its proof can be found on its Wikipedia page.

Comment: @EricWofsey What would you say then to this answer? http://math.stackexchange.com/a/440242/70349

Comment: That answer is really just explaining _why_ the convention is convenient (despite its insistence to the contrary).

Comment: It sounds like you want "$p \implies q$" to carry some semantic content about $p$ holding because of $q$: that $q$ fails without $p,$ or that there exists no universe with $p$ but not $q$, or that $p$ is somehow 'relevant' to $q$. But it's just convenient shorthand for "$q$ or not $p$."

Comment: @anomaly To repeat my comment on another answer: That follows directly from the definitions in the truth tables: $p \to q = (p \land q) \lor (\lnot p \land q) \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot q) = \lnot p \lor q$. It still does not address why we have both $(\lnot p \land q)$ and $(\lnot p \land \lnot q)$ in the definition. What I am asking is why we can't say that if $p$ is false, then $p \to q$ is simply undefined.

Comment: @ArukaJ: We _can_ say that, we just choose not to, because the standard definition has proven to be much more useful.  That is, we have learned from experience that the logical statement "$q$ or not $p$" is really useful to have a shorthand for, so we've made one and named it $p\implies q$.

Comment: Can you give an example of how it is a useful definition to have and why having it be undefined would be problematic?

Comment: celtschk's answer (which is basically the same as the answer of Peter Smith you linked to) is an excellent example: this definition is very natural and convenient when working with quantified statements.

Comment: Here is my answer ... http://math.stackexchange.com/a/48202/442

Comment: Get over you pre-conceptions that "P \implies Q" translates as "If P than Q".  That is not what it means.  Instead it means "whenever P, Q".  Surely it's obvious that whenever the moon is made of bacon wrapped apple monkey carburetors are precisely the same times as when both the moon is made of bacon wrapped apple monkeys carburetors and you are a better wake border than Gauss.  i.e. never.

Comment: @ArukaJ: Propositions in (first-order, etc.) logic are either true or false. There is no "undefined" option. My point is that it's really notation rather than a definition. It sounds like you're caught up in the idea of $\implies$ representing some sort of implication (which is hard to nail down); it's just shorthand for a particular, convenient disjunction.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Principle of Explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion)?  (I.e., that from a contradiction one may infer anything?)

Comment: @EricTowers It seems just as reasonable to conclude though that "from a contradiction one may infer nothing"

Comment: Someone tells you, "If you don't eat your meat, you can't have any pudding". You eat your meat. Does that somehow make their statement no longer true?

Comment: Informally? It doesn't make it true or false. If I don't eat my meat and you don't give me pudding, you held up your statement. If I don't eat my meat but you gave me pudding anyway, your statement was false. But if I eat my meat, we're going off-contract, here. You never told me what would happen if I did eat my meat.

Comment: @ArukaJ Because nothing was said about what happens if you do eat your meat, there can be no "breach of contract" if you eat your meat.  Only if you don't eat your meat yet are given pudding can the statement be deemed false.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is done so that classical propositional calculus follows some natural rules. Let's try to motivate this, without getting into technical details:

The expression "$P\Rightarrow Q$" should be read "$P$ implies $Q$", or "whenever $P$ is true, $Q$ is also true".

The negation of such an expression would be a counter-example, i.e., "there is some case in which $P$ is true but $Q$ is not".

So assume $P$ is not true. The negation "$\lnot(P\Rightarrow Q)$" is not true in this case, by our interpretation above, so "$P\Rightarrow Q$" must be true.

We are basically using the rules that either an expression or its negation should be true, and that the negation of the negation of an statement is the statement itself. These are basic rules which are natural and useful, even though as a consequence we have that "$P\Rightarrow Q$" is true whenever $P$ is false.

Comment: So we're saying that either $P \to Q$ is true or $\lnot(P \to Q)$ is true, right?  Agreed there. If $P \to Q$ is false when $P$ is true and $Q$ is false (also agreed), then $\lnot(P \to Q)$ should be true. By De Morgan's laws, this means $P$ is false or $Q$ is true. Oh holy crap.

Comment: I don't think the fact that P⇒Q is (vacuously) true if P is never true poses much of a problem in non-causal theorem spaces.  I think a bigger issue occurs when the same sort of logic is used in a causal universe.  Use R(A) to mean "Action A is reasonable".  An invitation to assume P should mean that anything that would be reasonable if P is true, is reasonable, i.e. for all A such that P→R(A), R(A).  In a causal universe, however, it would be helpful to distinguish between actions whose reasonableness would be *caused* by P, versus those without a forward causal link.

Answer (score 34):

Consider the statement:

> All multiples of 4 are even.

You would say that statement is true, right?

So let's formulate that in formal logic language:

> $\forall x: 4|x \implies 2|x$

(Here "$a|b$" means "$a$ divides $b$", that is, $b$ is a multiple of $a$.)

Now a $\forall$ statement is true if it is true whatever you insert for the quantified variable (after all,that's "for all" means). So let's try to insert $3$:

> $4|3 \implies 2|3$

But wait, $4|3$ is false! Moreover, $2|3$ is also false. So the only way for the original statement to be true is that the implication $\text{false}\implies\text{false}$ gives true.

A similar argument can be done for $\text{false}\implies\text{true}$.

Comment: This is an excellent example.

Comment: The reason I did not accept this answer is because it does not address the confusion directly. "4|3" does not represent a multiple of 4, so now we are no longer talking about what the original statement was discussing. Now we're talking about some manipulation that is false, which may have something true come from it, may have something false come from it. What I wanted to understand was why we'd still say $P \to Q$ is true even when $\lnot P$ leads to garbage results / truth or false either way.

Comment: @ArukaJ P=4|x and Q=2|x.  Where x=3, P and Q are both false. Where x=6, P is false and Q is true. With two-value logic, we can't possibly say either of those makes P⟹Q false, so the only reasonable alternative is to say that P⟹Q is defined to be true when P is false.

Comment: @MontyHarder My point is that we could also reasonably say it is undefined, as an alternative

Comment: @ArukaJ Every time you set x to a number divisible by 4, it's also divisible by 2. How can you say that "P⟹Q" is anything but true all of the time?

Comment: @ArukaJ "$\forall x: (P(x)\to Q(x) \text{ except when $P(x)\to Q(x)$ is undefined})$" is not at all a reasonable alternative.

Comment: @ArukaJ: But then you have to move the 4|x part into the quantifier (the for-all bit) somehow, in order to avoid quantifying over x which are not multiples of 4.  It turns out that it's simpler to just define the material implication (the right arrow symbol) as true in this case than to extend the rules of logical quantification to allow for something like this.

Comment: This doesn't address the original question of why not leave it undefined.  It only says that *if* it is defined, how it should be.

Answer (score 10):

In a more informal sense, I like to think that $P\implies Q$ means that "$Q$ is at least as true as $P$". Which means that if $P$ is something false, then anything is "more true"  than $P$, and thus the statement $P\implies Q$ is true.

Comment: But do we presuppose that falsity is less than truth in logic?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood well, strictly speaking there is no defined "measure" of truth/falsity - the above answer was merely meant as a useful heuristic. But logical implication translates into set-theoretical inclusion when you take sets of elements satisfying logical properties, which means that there are *at least as many* elements $x$ satisfying $Q$ than $P$ if $P(x)\implies Q(x)$, so in some ways this can be made more rigorous.

Comment: If there exist "at least as many" elements satisfying property Q than P does not imply that Q as bigger than P.  Q and P could have equivalent size.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood of course - I mean "at least as many" in the non-strict sense (less than or equal to). If they have the same size then this just means that the reverse implication $Q\implies P$ also holds i.e. the properties $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are *equivalent*.

Comment: You said "Which means that if P is something false, then anything is "more true" than P, and thus the statement P -> Q is true."  Now, if P(x) and Q(x) can hold as equivalent, then the reverse implication can hold, which would imply that a true proposition could imply a false proposition.  But, that never happens in propositional logic.  Consequently, your attempt to order truth values fails.

Answer (score 4):

Intuitively, consider $P \implies Q$ to be a promise. For example: I say, "If you ever jump over the moon, then I'll pay you a thousand dollars."

Now, some time passes and you obviously haven't jumped over the moon. The question is now effectively: Have I kept my promise true, or broken it (been false)?

It seems clear that I've kept that particular promise, granted that at no time was I obligated to give you the thousand dollars. In fact, even if I had given you a thousand dollars for some other service, it wouldn't have any bearing on that particular, empty offer.

Comment: But we could also say that we haven't been able to tell if you held up the promise either way, because I didn't jump over the moon to find out

Comment: @ArukaJ We can say definitively that Daniel has done everything he promised you he'd do (which in this case is nothing).

Comment: He hasn't done anything one way or the other, so the jury's still out

Comment: He gave you exactly the money he promised you.  The jury finds in his favor, and you have to pay court costs for filing a frivolous suit against him.

Comment: He didn't cheat me in that scenario so I wouldn't "file" -- he would have only cheated me if I jumped over the moon and he didn't pay me. But if I didn't jump over the moon yet, he has not yet cheated me nor has he followed through on anything.

Comment: @ArukaJ I've turned this line of discussion into a separate answer, by using the same numbers on both sides of the equation.  Suffice to say that by not jumping over the moon, you have guaranteed that Daniel has fulfilled his promise to you.  Therefore his promise is truthful.

Answer (score 3):

Consider any proof by contradiction, for example Euclid's proof of prime infinity.

> If $x$ is the largest prime number ("P"), then $y=\prod_{p\,\,prime} p+ 1$ is a prime ("Q").

This is a valid implication that can be shown with perfectly valid simple arguments. However, the premise is never satisfied. But within the proof, the reader may not yet see that it is ''nonsense'' at this step. You just follow the logic step by step. The fact that the premise is never satisfied does not make the logic (used to derive the claim above) less valid. So it is reasonable to assume that the claim above is True.

Comment: This answer reproduces a remarkably popular erroneous reading of the proof. The "Euclid number" $30031=2*3*5*7*11*13+1$ is not prime.

Comment: @KevinCarlson No, it doesn't. All you've proved is that if the claim is true, then $13$ cannot be the largest prime number. But that is the point: the claim is provably true, and what follows that claim is that *no* number can be the largest prime number.

Comment: Oh, huh, that's right. The wrong version just starts with a finite list of prime numbers, without assuming it's exhaustive.

Answer (score 2):

$p\to q$ is logically equivalent to $\neg p \vee q$.  Hence if $p$ is false, then $\neg p$ is true, so $\neg p \vee q$ is true.  This is the situation we call vacuously true.

Comment: Yes but that follows directly from the definitions in the truth tables: $p \to q = (p \land q) \lor (\lnot p \land q) \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot q) = \lnot p \lor q$. It still does not address why we have both $(\lnot p \land q)$ and $(\lnot p \land \lnot q)$ in the definition.

Comment: @ArukaJ no, the definition you give follows from *this*. If $p$ is false, then $\neg p \vee x$ is independent of $x$, because "or" is satisfied by *one* true thing.

Comment: @ArukaJ, the reason the definition is the way it is, is because people find this definition useful.  If you don't  like it, make your own definition, of your own connective.

Comment: How do you know that logical equivalence holds without having the truth tables for $\lor$ and ->, and $\lnot$ in the first place?

Comment: The definition works, because a logical equivalence exists.  Were it the case that no logical equivalence existed between (p -> q) and ($\lnot$p $\lor$ q), then the definition would not qualify as sound.

Answer (score 2):

One way to look at this is by set inclusion:

"$P \implies Q$" is the same as saying that "the set of mathematical statements that have $P$ as true (call it $S_P$) is a subset of the set of statements that have $Q$ as true (call it $S_Q$)." So if $P$ is false, then $S_P = \emptyset$. It follows that whatever $S_Q$ is, $\emptyset = S_P \subset S_Q$. Hence, $P \implies Q$ is **vacuously** true. $Q$ by itself is not vacuously true: you need the antecendent, $P \implies$, for the "vacuous" property to make sense.

Answer (score 2):

This is what Terence Tao [has to say](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/books/analysis-i/#comment-469981):

> This is discussed in Appendix A.2 of my book. The notion of
>   implication used in mathematics is that of material implication, which
>   in particular assigns a true value to any vacuous implication. One
>   could of course use a different convention for the notion of
>   implication, however material implication is very useful for the
>   purpose of proving mathematical theorems, as it allows one to use
>   implications such as “if A, then B” without having to first check
>   whether A is true or not. Material implication also obeys a number of
>   useful properties, such as specialisation: if for instance one knows
>   for every x that P(x) implies Q(x), then one can specialise this to a
>   specific value of x, say 3, and conclude that P(3) implies Q(3). Note
>   though that by doing so a non-vacuous implication can become a vacuous
>   implication. For instance, we know that $x \geq 5$ implies $x^2 \geq
> > 25$ for any real number $x$; specialising this to the real number 3,
>   we obtain the vacuous implication that $3 \geq 5$ implies $3^2 \geq 25$.
>
> The way I like to think of material implication is as follows: the
>   assertion that A implies B is just saying that “B is at least as true
>   as A”. In particular, if A is true, then B has to be true also; but if
>   A is false, then the material implication allows B to be either true
>   or false, and so the implication is true no matter what the truth
>   value of B is.

Answer (score 1):

OK, here's a crack at it, based on something we had going in comments.  It's an argument by analogy, which isn't really a good idea, but I think it can help you make sense of why it has to be this way:

I'm running a currency exchange and promise to give you one Cuban Convertible Peso for each US Dollar you give me.

You give me USD 10 on Monday, and I give you CUC 10 in exchange.

On Tuesday you give me nothing.  I give you nothing in exchange.

On Wednesday, you give me USD 5.  I give you CUC 5 in exchange.

On Thursday, you try to give me a Euro.  I could just accept EUR 1 from you as a gift, offer some amount of change for it, or push it back to you and point at the sign that says I trade USD for CUC.  No matter which of these I choose, I am still fulfilling my promise.

On Friday, you didn't give me anything, but I give you CUC 0.25 out of the goodness of my heart.  Or maybe because you're amusing me and that's worth rewarding.

No amount of **not** giving me USD can change the truth of the statement "Monty is an honest currency broker who keeps his promise to give at least as much CUC for every USD you give him".

When you gave me USD 0, I gave you at least CUC 0.  For the four days, you've given me USD 15 and I've given you CUC 15.25 (and maybe some more for the EUR 1).  I'm absolutely keeping my promise every single day, and if you claim I'm not keeping my promise on the days you gave me USD 0, then you're lying, because I gave you at least CUC 0 on those days.  You can't even argue that "the jury's out" on whether I gave you at least as many CUC each day as you gave me in USD, because 0=0.  To do so would itself be untrue, and an actual jury might rule you've libeled me by doing that.

Similarly, to treat (P⟹Q) as anything but true when P is false would itself be false.

Answer (score 1):

A different point of view is to think of an argument as a chain of lights. A light is lit if you know it is true.

P implies Q says that when you manage to ignite the P light then P ignites the Q light too. However, if P is not lit then it doesn't mean that you can't light Q in some other way.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume the principle of bivalence, and we want the law of identity to hold true, I answer the question by saying that the reason lies in that logical implication is not logical equivalence.

The law of identity for all propositions x, (x ⟹ x), ensures that if p is false and q is false, then (p ⟹ q) is true.

The true does not imply the false, thus if p is true and q is false, (p ⟹ q) is false.

Thus, our truth table looks like the following so far:

```
⟹     false  true
false  true     ?
true   false  true
```

Now if the question mark got filled in by false, then ⟹ would indicate logical equivalence.  But, we don't logical equivalence for logical implication.  We don't want to hold that {($\alpha$ ⟹ $\beta$), $\beta$} $\vdash$ $\alpha$.  And we want ⟹ to work out as truth-functional.  In other words (false ⟹ true) matches to some truth value.  Consequently, (false ⟹ true) holds true.

Answer (score 0):

If the light is green, I can make a right turn. If the light is red, I might still be able to make the turn-it depends if the sign says "no turn on red" and if any cars are coming. But you don't know whether I can make the turn if all you know is that the light is red.

If you know that I can make the turn, you don't know what color the light is- it could either be green, it a red light that I'm allowed to make the turn at. But if you know that I couldn't make the turn, it's guaranteed that the light was red.

As another example, if I rob a bank, I go to jail. However, if I don't rob a bank, that doesn't guarantee that I don't get arrested- I could have committed a different crime. On the same note, if I am in jail, you don't know if I robbed a bank or not, but if I'm not in jail, I definitely haven't broken in to a bank.