# When should I classify a statement as "undefined" versus "vacuously true/false": implications for induction

Tags: logic, terminology, predicate-logic

Although this question has sort of been asked before ([Why aren't vacuous truths just undefined?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1886345/why-arent-vacuous-truths-just-undefined)), I think my question is emphasizing a somewhat different aspect. Rather than knowing "why" vacuous truths aren't just undefined...I want to know **when** one should treat a statement as undefined, instead of vacuously true (or vacuously false).

In Tao's *Analysis I*, there is the following passage:

> "To summarize so far, among all the objects studied in mathematics, some of the objects happen to be sets; and if $x$ is an object and $A$ is a set, then either $x \in A$ is true or $x \in A$ is false. (If $A$ is not a set, we leave the statement $x \in A$ undefined; for instance, we consider the statement $3 \in 4$ to be neither be true or false, but simply meaningless, since 4 is not
>   a set.)"

So while this certainly makes sense...I am reluctant to claim that I comfortably know when to declare something as being vacuous versus undefined. If I were to rephrase this slightly, I could say: *Prove to me that $3$ is **not** an element of $4$*.

...Well, unfortunately, $4$ is not a set so I have no way of disproving your claim. However, this sounds vaguely similar to any sort of argument that invokes the "vacuously true" approach. (And for the situation of a base case of an induction proof, it is quite important to make the distinction between "undefined" and "vacuously true", I would think!) Could anyone offer an explanation that will clear this up for me?

Cheers~

Comment: You might want to check out the idea of a many-sorted language, which I think is what the author is tacitly getting at. The idea is that $3\in 4$ isn't treated as syntactically correct in the first place, and we only give truth values to syntactically correct expressions.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Interesting. So the statement $\forall n, P(n)$ for $n \in \{\}$ has been "Agreed upon by mathematicians" as being syntactically correct...and therefore vacuously true (i.e. the community agrees that statements about the null set  in this fashion are syntactically correct)?

Comment: In a two-sorted language that distinguishes between objects and sets, and only allows the former to be members of the latter, then yes, it's well-formed and vacuously true. Note that working in a two-sorted theory is not a standard way to handle things; in set theory there's only one sort, and $3\in 4$ has a truth value (it's true under the usual definitions), so this issue of undefinedness is an artifact of a particular sort of treatment.

Comment: Your question reminds me of [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4154853/conceptual-doubts-based-on-continuity/4154878#comment9766995_4154878) in which I queried whether the statement "it is false that $\frac1x$ is continuous at $0$" is non-meaningful or is true. As it is couched in natural language, it feels like any consensus may not be strong, compared to asking whether a more formal statement is true/false or undefined.

Answer (score -1):

As I understand, in classical logic, if the antecedent of any implication is false, then that implication is said to to be *vacuously true*. For any object $x$ and proposition $P$, for example, we have, the implication $x \in \emptyset \implies P$ being (vacuously) true. Likewise, $0=1 \implies P$.

A function $f: A \to B$ is said to be undefined for some object $x$ means only that $x \notin A$. I have never heard of a syntactically correct logical proposition being "undefined" or "meaningless."