# About an implication in logic or mathematics.

Tags: logic

The following is a question in an entrance examination of a Japanese university.

A quadrilateral $ABCD$ is inscribed in a circle with a radius of $65/8$. The perimeter of this quadrilateral is $44$ and the lengths of $BC$ and $CD$ are both $13$. What are the lengths of the remaining two sides $AB$ and $DA$?

The answer is $AB = 14, DA = 4$ or $AB = 4, DA = 14$.

I think if such a quadrilateral did not exist, this problem would be a very bad problem. So I think we must check the existence of such a quadrilateral. I asked a man about my question. He said $A \implies B$ is true even if $A$ is not true.

Which is correct, me or him?

Comment: If $B$ is true, $A\Rightarrow B$ is true.

Comment: Personally, I'm more inclined to wonder why it even mentions a rectangle in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, my english is very bad. Not a rectangle.I mean a quadrilateral.

Comment: But how's the question related to the quadrilateral?

Comment: I would guess that there are theorems that will tell us what sort of quadrilateral has a circumcircle. The problem here is given as a premise, say $A$ (the perimeter and various lengths given). Assuming this, i.e. assuming $A$ (not claiming it's true), we have solved the problem and gotten that from $A$ we get $B$ (the solution, using know, valid results). The modus ponens could then be used to claim that $B$ is true, provided we knew $A$ is true.

Comment: The man is correct.  Please see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232309/how-to-interpret-material-conditional-and-explain-it-to-freshmen?s=1|92.0609)

Comment: By definition $a\to b$ is true, unless $a$ is true and $b$ is false.  We can also put that as follows:  $a\to b$ is true whenever $a$ is false, or $b$ true, (or both $a$ is false and $b$ is true).

Comment: When $a$ is false, the fact that $a\to b$ is true is called a [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth)

Comment: Thank you very much, Javi, Saucy O'Path, AnyAD, amWhy.

Comment: A real number $x$ satisfies $x^2 = -1$. What is the value of $x^4$? We cannot calculate $x^4$ because such a real number $x$ does not exist.

Comment: As you say, for the question to be good, the quadrilateral needs to exist. By the logic of implication, if the quadrilateral doesn't exist then *any* answer would be correct. As the person answering the question, though, this isn't your problem.

Comment: The idea is called "The principle of explosion", also sometimes "vacuous implication".  It tends to confuse a lot of those who are new to formal logic, but it is a convention you are probably already using without knowing it.

Answer (score 1):

The man you talked to is right, and you are wrong.

Logic and mathematics do not deal with what is actually true, but asks: *if* something is true, *then* what follows?  This is what we mean by the logical implication, for which indeed we use $A \Rightarrow B$. That is, $A \Rightarrow B$ is the case if and on if: $B$ logically follows from $A$. And given the standard axioms of mathematics involving the objects involved in this question, the answer is:

Yes! If we *assume* that:

> A quadrilateral $ABCD$ is inscribed in a circle with a radius of $65/8$. The perimeter of this quadrilateral is 44 and the lengths of $BC$ and $CD$ are both $13$.

then it *follows* that:

> the lengths of the remaining two sides $AB$ and $DA$ is $AB=14,DA=4$ or $AB=4,DA=14$.

Answer (score 0):

The way I interpret A$\implies$B is true even if A is not true is, the sum of the two sides is $18$ whether or not the individual sides are $4$ and $14$ which is a correct statement but does not answer the question as to whether they are in fact $4$ and $14$. In this respect, you are correct to want to confirm these values.