# Axiomatic derivation - what does instancing an axiom practically entail?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, axioms, hilbert-calculus

I'm stunned by the chapter in my coursebook (which is in Dutch, so please advice if I am mistranslating any of the terms) about deriving from a system of axioms and derivation rules. The exercise is to prove the following:

$$p \vdash_S q \rightarrow p$$

Step one is to assume p. That makes sense to me: if p is true then p is true.

$$ p \vdash_S p $$

Step two is to make an instance of the axiom $\varphi \rightarrow (\psi  \rightarrow \varphi)$; replacing $\varphi$ with p and  $\psi$ with q. That yields:

$$\vdash_S p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow p)$$

Final step is modus ponens which I also logically understand so I won't repeat it here. My befuddlement is with step two, with instancing an axiom. What does that mean in practical terms?

I recognise that $\varphi \rightarrow (\psi  \rightarrow \varphi)$ is a tautology, it is technically true for every two propositions regardless of whether they are related. But by instancing the axiom I am introducing a relation between p and q out of thin air; in fact q did not exist in my original assumptions.

By taking "I see a bird in the sky" for p, and "Tom Hanks releases a new movie" for q, by doing this I can "prove" that Tom Hanks has some relation to birds. While the technical definition of $\rightarrow$ allows for the right term to be true when the left isn't, so there could still be birds without Tom Hanks, there's still a relation in the opposite direction: when Hanks releases a movie, birds have to appear. So I feel that instancing an axiom is just making stuff up.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The expression $\varphi \rightarrow (\psi  \rightarrow \varphi)$ is an axiom. You said you know this is a tautology. Axioms should be tautologies (in a certain sense), after all you want axioms to always be true. The axiom is critical in allowing you to infer $p\to (q\to p)$, otherwise how would you do it? Classical propostional calculus does not care about relations (or lack thereof) like the one you exemplified, it just cares about symbols.

Comment: The only relationship between birds and Tom Hanks that you have established is that they both occur in that sentence of yours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> That makes sense to me: if $p$ is true then $p$ is true.

> I recognise that $\phi\to(\psi\to\phi)$ is a tautology, it is technically true for every two propositions regardless of whether they are related.

These two remarks suggest to me that you are approaching logic from a biased perspective: it seems that a proof needs to make sense to you intuitively in order to be a proof.

In a certain sense, this is of course desirable, since we use proofs to make conclusions that ultimately *make sense* to other people (or at least to other mathematicians). But formal logic is actually far more than that. It studies the parts of "making sense" by removing all baggage that is introduced by our intuition, and reducing arguments to nothing but the utmost essential.

So, let's get rid of our intuition first, and then reintroduce it later.

---

A logical proof can be seen as a recipe of sorts. You start with basic ingredients, which are **axioms** and **inference rules**, and then you cook up a **proof** by instantiating axioms (i.e. producing a sentence with the same structure as the axiom, although the variables may be replaced) and applying inference rules. *And that's all*. There is nothing telling us that the axioms or the inference rules should make sense, or that they should satisfy certain requirements motivated by our intuition. In a certain sense, a proof is therefore nothing more than the manipulation of symbols, and these symbols can be lacking of any "meaning" as far as the proof is concerned.

Let's take a look at your proof.

Step one is to assume $p$, because our goal is to derive $p\vdash q\to p$, therefore $p$ can be taken as an assumption, since it's one of the expressions before the $\vdash$ symbol.

Step two is to make an instantiation of the axiom $\phi\to(\psi\to\phi)$, not because this axiom makes sense, but because *it's an axiom*, and the rules dictate that we may always instantiate axioms. Instantiating axioms means that we can replace its variables with anything we like, thus we can replace $\phi$ with $p$ and $\psi$ with $q$. We have therefore derived that $\vdash p\to (q\to p)$.

Finally, since we have derived both $\vdash p$ and $\vdash p\to(q\to p)$ the modus ponens inference rule tells us that we are allowed to derive $\vdash q\to p$.

Since we did things exactly by following the rules (taking assumptions, instantiating axioms, using inference rules), we have made a valid proof.

---

Now, to get our intuition back into the picture, the axioms and rules of propositional calculus are chosen to make *intuitive* sense as well. We can see $p\to q$ as symbolising the meaning of "$p$ must be true, or $q$ must be false". This is the *semantics* of the expression $p\to q$, and indeed, the semantics of the axioms and rules of propositional calculus make *intuitive* sense for many people.

Note that this also answers your second question: there does not have to be a (causal) relation between $p$ and $q$ under these semantics of $p\to q$. Your intuition should be that this stands for *either $p$ is true, or $q$ is false*.

You can totally create a logic where $p\to q$ has different semantics, such as one where $p\to q$ can only be valid if $p$ and $q$ are related to each other. An example of such a (collection of) logic(s) is [relevance logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relevance_logic). But that is a different system than the classical propositional logic that you're studying. It has different axioms, different inference rules, and different semantics.

---

As an example to challenge your intuition, I could define a logic with the axioms:

- $\psi \sim \bigcirc \psi$
- $\bigcirc \psi \sim \triangle \psi$

and the inference rule:

- $\phi,\phi\sim \psi\vdash \psi$

Then you could prove that $p\vdash \triangle p$. Does it make any *intuitive* sense? No, because we have no idea what these symbols mean. But can you create a valid proof? Absolutely:

We assume $p$, then by the first axiom we can derive $p\sim \bigcirc p$, so by the inference rule $p,p\sim\bigcirc p\vdash \bigcirc p$. Now by the second axiom we can derive $\bigcirc p\sim \triangle p$, so since we have derived $\bigcirc p$ and $\bigcirc p\sim \triangle p$ we can use the inference rule to derive $\triangle p$. Therefore $p\vdash \triangle p$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought about it for a few hours and will probably need some more time still. The book tells me that this kind of logic is used for automated decision-making processes. If I divorce $\rightarrow$ from its name "implication" and use it for just the truth table without making any preconceptions about whether the two things are actually related in reality, thus allowing me to pull conditions out of thin air and connect them with my observations in so many ways - then it is not at all obvious to me how this system can still be used for any practical situations.

Comment: Just in this example, p is an assumption so it comes from my observations or hypothetical observations. q on the other hand, is a variable that I dreamt up because I filled an axiom with q. So how could any result containing a q, a variable not even referenced in the starting assumptions, still say anything about reality?

Comment: @KeizerHarm It is actually called "material implication". But please note that $q\to p$ is semantically equivalent to $\lnot q\lor p$ in propositional logic (you can prove this in the propositional calculus). You should not divorce $\to$ from the name "implication", but rather, you should divorce the meaning of the word "implication" in natural (everyday) language from the meaning of "implication" within mathematics / logic. Because mathematics almost exclusively uses "implies" as in $q\to p$ from propositional logic.

Comment: As for its usefulness, it is extermely useful. Classical logic, especially with quantifiers (first-order logic) is ubiquitous within mathematics and computing science. The discovery of propositional calculus has directly led to the creation of computers, and first-order logic is the basic logical vocabulary of the vast majority of mathematics. My best argument for why we use material implication, is that it makes everything **a lot** easier, compared to requiring antecedent and consequent to be related. For example, classical logic is a lot simpler than the relevance logic I mentioned.

Comment: Finally, note that $q\to p$ and $p$ do not say *the same thing*. The fact that you can prove $q\to p$ from the assumption $p$ means that $q\to p$ is actually a *weaker assumption* than that just $p$ would be. It doesn't say anything about the truth of $p$ nor about the truth of $q$, but it states that **if** $q$ is true, **then** $p$ must be true. When $q$ is false, then it is still true that **if** $q$ is true, then $p$ must be true as well, since this is "fiction": $q$ is false after all. Similarly, if $p$ is already true, it doesn't matter whether $q$ is true or not.

Comment: Note that we are talking about mathematical truth here: classical propositional logic does not work well for applications in daily conversation. That's why we don't use classical logic for such applications, but rather use other logical systems (and there are a lot of them!). However, in mathematics, the truth of a statement doesn't vary over time or under circumstances, thus material implication makes sense.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232309/ for more discussion about the interpretation of implication within mathematics

Answer (score 2):

> there's still a relation in the opposite direction: when Hanks releases a movie, birds have to appear

No, this is not correct. You have:

$q$ = Tom Hanks releases a new movie

$p$ = I see a bird the sky

The axiom you are instancing is: $p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow p)$.

This does *not* say, "when Hanks releases a movie, birds have to appear". That would be $q \rightarrow p$.

Instead you have $p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow p)$, which is "If there is [already] a bird in the sky, then if Tom Hanks releases a movie, then there is a bird in the sky." Of course, this is true.