# How is it that "p implies q" is equivalent to "not p or q"?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I came across the following example that explains the Law of Implication, which I cannot wrap my head around.

How is it that:$$p \Rightarrow q$$

Is logically equivalent to:

$$\neg p \lor q$$?

Comment: Did you try making a truth table?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Help to understand material implication](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38713/help-to-understand-material-implication)

Comment: As with many things, having a few quintessential examples in your pocket helps.  "*If $x$ is a rational number then $x^2$ is rational*"   and note that $5$ and $5^2$ are both rational, that $\pi$ and $\pi^2$ are both not, and that $\sqrt{3}$ is not but $\sqrt{3}^2$ is.